# Push DIV to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a countdown timer and a responsive wallpaper. Now what I want to do is that center the div at the bottom of the page & it should always stay at bottom. I went through some similar questions on StackOverFlow but by implementing that code I used to get a scrollbar or there was some space left at the bottom of the page. These are the following codes I used:

```
 div { 
   position: absolute; 
   height: 100px; 
   top: 100%; 
   margin-top:-100px; 
}
```

The above code gave me a scroll bar and the following code leaves some space at the bottom

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

This is the CSS on the index page for the Responsive image :

```
<style>

body {

background-attachment: fixed;

background-image: url(bg.png);

background-position: top center;

background-repeat: no-repeat;



margin:0;

padding: 0;



background-size: cover;

-moz-background-size: cover;

-webkit-background-size: cover; }

</style>
```

& this is the style.css which I have

```
    body, p, span, div                                                              { font-family: 'Droid Sans', arial, serif;font-size:12px;line-height:18px;color:#6d6d6d; } 


.countdown                                                                      { padding-top:15px;width:100%;margin:auto; }
.countdown .countdown_section                                                   { background:url('images/backcountdown.png') no-repeat 1px top;float:left;width:54px;height:145px;margin:0 5px;text-align:center;line-height:6px; }
.countdown .countdown_amount                                                    { font-size:15px;color:#ab7100; text-shadow:0 0.8px #fedd98; line-height:52px; font-weight:bold; text-align: left; }
.countdown span                                                                 { font-size:8px;color:#999999;text-transform:uppercase;line-height:26px; }
```

Actually there's just one div class on the index page named "countdown clearfix". I'm a noob at HTML/CSS so I needed some help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also try the [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) technique:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    /* Add styles from next code block here if you want them in the same file */
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Regular page contents -->

    <div id="push"><!-- Leave this element empty --></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <!-- Countdown goes here -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

With the following CSS (in a separate file or inside the `<style>` tag):

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -100px; /* <- If you change this height... */
}
#footer, #push {
  height: 100px;         /* <- ...then you should also change this height! */
}

body {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url(bg.png);
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
}
```

Notice how `<html>`, `<body>` and `<div id="wrapper">` are all 100% height of the viewport, and that the `<div id="wrapper">` then allows some room at the bottom with a negative margin of 100px, which is then filled by the `<div id="footer">`. The `<div id="push">` is just there to assure that the room for the footer is always available.

If the page content is smaller than the viewport, the footer will 'stick' to the bottom of the browser viewport, if the content is bigger, then the footer will always be at the bottom.

Comment: Actually I just have one DIV & that Div is the footer so how should I proceed I'm a newbie ?

Comment: I copied your body styles into my example, can you try it and see if works?

Comment: Updated my stylesheet check post.

Answer (score 2):

to place a div 100px high/1000px wide div in the center-bottom you would just need:

```
#bottom-div {
    height:100px;
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: It showed me a little scrollbar & some space was left at the bottom.

Comment: you must have another stylesheet adding a margin to the bottom. can you post your entire stylesheet? also make sure your body tag has margin and padding set to 0.

Comment: Even after updating the stylesheet I still see a lil scrollbar.

Comment: Removed the <code>height: 145px;</code> & it started working with your code. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px; /* this and */
    bottom: 100px; /* this should correspond with eachother */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Some space is left at the bottom, around 30 or 40px that's the problem with every code I use. Any other alternatives ? or is it possible that  there might be some conflicting code ?

Comment: As the above comment says, some space is still left at the bottom even after having 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

use this exact code and it will work.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:auto;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
#wrap {
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    text-align:left;    
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
}
#bottom {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    height: 50px;
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    width:1000px;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="bottom">
            bottom
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check now I've updated the style.css to what it is actually so I won't be using so many DIVs.